# Where can I find the download link to download Security patch APSB23-35 and Security patch APSB23-17 for open source Magento 2.4.5 p-1

Tags: magento2.4.5p1

Where can I find the download link or composer command to download Security patch APSB23-35 and Security patch APSB23-17 for open source Magento 2.4.5 p-1

I checked on the adobe portal, https://marketplace.magento.com/, etc and it is nowhere to be found.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no security patches are available for APSB23-35 and APSB23-17. To apply the fix, you need to upgrade to the latest version.

Currently, only Magento 2.4.4, 2.4.5, and 2.4.6 receive [support](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/planning/lifecycle-policy.html?lang=en). So you can upgrade to one of the following versions to get the fix:

- 2.4.6-p1 for 2.4.6 and earlier
- 2.4.5-p3 for 2.4.5-p2 and earlier
- 2.4.4-p4 for 2.4.4-p3 and earlier